# Query to calculate Mysql row max size

Tags: mysql, byte, size, row, utf8mb4

Say I have a db table with 5 fields.

```
id bigint(20)
name varchar(255)
place varchar(255)
DOB date
about TEXT
```

Maximum row size is 65535 bytes in MySQL that is shared among all columns in the table, except TEXT/BLOB columns.

I need a query which will give me the maximum row size in bytes for this table so that I can check if the max size exceeds 65535. The charset used is utf8mb4. I need something like this

(20*8 + 255*4 + 255*4 + 3) = 2203 
 the size of about field is ignored since the type is TEXT.

Comment: You can query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`. Use the `DATA_TYPE` and `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` columns.

Comment: I don't think there's anything built-in that will return the size of a datatype. You can use a `CASE` expression or create a table of your own that maps type names to size.

Comment: *20*8* BIGINT(20) is NOT 20 BIGINTs... :)

Comment: @Akina You are right, thanks

Comment: @Barmar Will try to write to do that

Answer (score 2):

It is much simpler -- Write and run the `CREATE TABLE` statement.  It will spit at you if it is too large.

Meanwhile, here are *some* of the flaws in your attempt:

- `BIGINT` is 8 bytes; the `(20)` is useless information.
- Each `VARCHAR` needs 1- or 2-bytes for length field.
- `TEXT` takes some amount of space toward the 64K limit.
- There is a bunch of "overhead" for each column and the row, so it is really impractical to try to compute the length.
- Note also -- When the length gets too large, some of the `VARCHARs` may be treated like `TEXT`.  That is they won't necessarily count toward the 64K limit.  However, they will leave a 20-byte pointer in their place.

If you are tempted to have a table with too many too-big columns, describe the table to us; we can suggest improvements, such as:

- `BIGINT` is rarely needed; use a smaller int type.
- Don't blindly use `(255)` is has several drawbacks.  Analyze your data and pick a more realistic limit.
- Be aware that there are four `ROW_FORMATs`.  `DYNAMIC` is probably optimal for you.  (Old versions of MySQL did not have `Dynamic`.
- Parallel tables  (Two tables with the same PK)
- Normalization  (Replacing a common string with a smaller INT.)
- Don't use a bunch of columns as an "array"; make another table.  (Example: 3 phone number columns.)

Have you hit any `INDEX` limits yet?  It smells like you might get bitten by that, too.  Write up the `CREATE TABLE`, including tentative indexes.  We'll chew it up and advise you.